# Cant specify background color on header

Tags: html, css, sass

I can't seem to specify the color on the header for my website.

The code is here:

```css
.header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  position: relative;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75vh, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75vh, 0 100%);

  &__logo-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    left: 4rem;
    z-index: 4;
  }

  &__logo {
    height: 35px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  &__text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}



.video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(30, 95, 156, 1) 1%,
    rgba(16, 55, 130, 0.2637429971988795) 100%
  );

  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}




.hor-nav{
  position: fixed;
 top: 40px;
 right: 40px;
 height: 50px;
  z-index: 20;
  color: $color-white;
  
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  
  color:$color-white;
}
li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-bg{
  background-color:#2998ff;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
      <div class="gradient">
      </div>
      <video autoplay muted loop class="video">
        <source src="img/bg-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <div class="header-bg">
      <div class="header__logo-box">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://logos.xmltv.se/en.tlc.discovery.dk.png" alt="logo" class="header__logo" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="hor-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Invest</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Insights</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Performance</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div></div>
        </header>
```

I want to put the background color of #2998ff; to my header The background needs to be placed behind the navigation and the logo.

I've tried putting it in one div .header-bg and it still dosen't seem to work the way I want it to work.

Comment: I solved it !  .header-bg{
   background-color: #2998ff !important;
   position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 66px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="background-color:#2998ff;"></div>
```

You should try something like this

Comment: that does't work it seems like I am not selecting logo and navigation right

Comment: it should look something like on this website https://www.fieldchat.com

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear. Could you attach your css and html files here

Comment: please check whether you have added closing quotation after the semicolon as I showed in above answer

Comment: I tried your code here.  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8J6RLWMC7O3 .Check it out. It does work !!!

Comment: this is a css question, I already have a background for the entire homepage. I just need a background behind my header ( logo and navigation )

Comment: Plus inline css is a bad practice

Comment: okay. then try adding !important in front of background color to make sure it is not replaced with any other background colors as this - > .header-bg{
  background-color:#2998ff !important ;
}

Comment: still doesnt work I think its something with positioning or dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes style definitions can overlap others. Try using !important at the end of the background-color declaration.

Comment: Set background color of **hor-nav**

Comment: when I do that it works but only for the hor-nav I want it to be behind the logo and hor-nav

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on.

## browser web tools

All of these can be expiremented and tested in real time by using right click -> inspect element, or open web dev tools. If you're doing anything with web developement, they are insanely useful. Learn how to use them.

## Invalid CSS

`&` is not a valid operator in CSS. If you're using a pre-processor like `LESS`, you need to run it to output CSS the browser can understand.

```
&__logo-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    left: 4rem;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

## Which CSS Selector do you want?

If you want to select all `<header>` elements, you would use

```
header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you want anyone with the `class` name `header` use:

```
.header {
    background-color: red;   
}
```

If you want *only one specific element* that has the ID of `header`, use:

```
#header {
    background-color: red;   
}
```

If you want any div that's a child of header:

```
header div {
    background-color: red;   
}
```

Search for "css tutorials" and the word "selectors" for more info.

## css overwriting?

> Sometimes style definitions can overlap others

It's not this case of overwiting this time. Check your webpage with browser's DOM inspector / web tools. The `header` background is being set if you use the `header` selector. Select the element you want, to see all of it's computed CSS properties.

There's overlapping divs with transparency, making it harder to tell. Set all elements to a solid background color, to see. You'll probably need to add `padding` or `margin` to see them. Otherwise, the `header div` covers your `header`.

## Mentioned above inline CSS

You do not want inline CSS, like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#2998ff"></div>
```

That will increase filesize and makes it harder to mantain code. It's a lot more work to make any  change.  Instead, use the right combinations of selectors. You can use heirarchy (like the first `<p>` element inside a `<header>`), or by classes, or by Ids.  You can use multiple css classes on a single element. (I can't tell from the markup what you are expecting. You're probably overcomplicating the layout.